# Steam account security: list of allowed computers on SteamGuard

Tags: steam

When I login on the Steam website on a new computer, it uses Steamguard to send a code to my email and asks me to copy that code on a dialog on the website. It also asks me to set a nickname to the computer and adds it to a list of allowed recognized computers.

**Where can I see / edit this list?**

[image: Steam Guard Warning]

Comment: I'd be glad if anyone could provide an English version of this message.

Comment: @robotnik thanks for providing and English version, but now it doesn't contain *the key element* my question was about (the computer nickname!)

Comment: my bad, I missed that part. I'll rollback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I looked at the different strings used by Steam Guard and the only relevant ones I've found are when there is reasonable doubt that your account has been compromised. This is an example I actually got when I logged onto Steam on my laptop:

[image: Steam Guard Notification]:

Here's the other alternative:

> Since you last logged in from this computer, your account credentials were used and Steam Guard was disabled from another place.
>
> Please confirm these sessions were authorized by you:
>
> If any listed sessions were not authorized by you, select 'No, this was not me' to change your Steam password and email address, deauthorize other locations and re-enable Steam Guard.

Both dialogues are referenced by [this published FAQ article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7137-PGHL-8428) on Steam Guard Notification.

---

Just to be complete, if you want to deauthorize the all other systems you have previously used, you can go to the settings in the menu, press the *"Manage Steam Guard account security"* button and check the *"Deauthorize all other computers now"* checkmark before pressing next.

[image]

Comment: Wait, did you reverse engineered Steam?

Comment: @ruda.almeida Reverse Engineering, the nice way of saying "hack"

Comment: @ruda I'm just looking at the tokens used by it i18n.

Comment: I just noticed today the last screenshot example and was going to put that as a second answer, but you guys are faster. Thanks @alexanderpas